# Update table based on data from another table

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I have a table called `DWCUST` that has a variety of misspelled gender values.
I want to replace the invalid `GENDER` value with the correct value according to the `GENDERSPELLING` table.

So for example, if there is a field in the in the `gender` column of the `dwcust` table that says `Male`, i want it to be changed to `M`.

this is the gender spelling table:

```
Invalid Value      New_Value

        MAIL       M
        WOMAN      F
        FEM        F
        FEMALE     F
        MALE       M
        GENTLEMAN  M
        MM         M
        FF         F
        FEMAIL     F
```

This is the update i have tried so far, but i keep getting the error: 'GS.NEW_VALUE' invalid identifier.

```
UPDATE (SELECT DW.GENDER 
FROM DWCUST DW, GENDERSPELLING GS
WHERE DW.GENDER = GS.INVALID_VALUE)
SET DW.GENDER = GS.NEW_VALUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE DWCUST t1
SET GENDER = (SELECT NEW_VALUE FROM GENDERSPELLING t2
              WHERE t1.GENDER = t2.INVALID_VALUE)
WHERE GENDER NOT IN ('M', 'F');
```

This would attempt to do a lookup for any gender which is not already `M` or `F` (the accepted values).  If there is a chance that an incorrect value might not be covered by the `GENDERSPELLING` table, then my query could be slightly modified to leave the current value as is.